# How to join nested JSON indices to multiple rows in SQL by primary key

Tags: json, sql-server, join

I am trying to update several rows in SQL with JSON.

I'd like to match a primary key on a table row to an index nested in an array of JS objects.

Sample data:

```
let json = [{
  "header": object_data,
  "items": [{
    "id": {
      "i": 0,
      "name": "item_id"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": object_data,
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 4,
      "name": "item_id4"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": object_data,
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 17,
      "name": "item_id17"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": object_data,
      "text": "some_text"
  }}]
}]
```

Sample table:

```
i  |  json                     | item_id
---+---------------------------+---------
0  | entire_object_at_index_0  | item_id
4  | entire_object_at_index_4  | item_id4
17 | entire_object_at_index_17 | item_id17
```

`entire_object_at_index`, meaning appending the item data to the header to create a new object for each row.

```
"header" "some_data",
"items": [{
  "id": {
    "i": 0,
    "name": "item_id1"
  },
  "meta": {
    "data": "some_data",
    "text": "some_text"
  }
}]
```

SQL:

```
update someTable set 
json = json_value(@jsons, '$') -- not sure how to join on index here
item_id = json_value(@jsons, '$.items[?].id.name' -- not sure how to select by index here
where [i] = json_query(@jsons, '$.items.id.i')
```

Comment: What's supposed to end up in `json`? `meta`? `meta.data`? The object holding `id` and `meta`? Something else? In other words, what should the table look like afterwards? Also, is the index in the array truly relevant, or can we just resolve everything by matching `i`?

Comment: In `JSON` it's a new object that has the header data and item data for that key/index.

Comment: The index is not truly relevant, it's just matching the table key `i` to the object index `id.i`.

Comment: So, just to be clear, in every row of the table the `header` and `items` array should be repeated, with the `items` array having only a single element in each case? Are you allowed to assume the structure (i.e. `header` and `items`)? I ask because that's simpler than (say) the query needing to work even if someone adds a new property that has to be replicated to the new object. In the former case, we can just `select`, in the latter case we have to get tricky with replacement, because T-SQL has no convenient way to edit JSON arrays.

Comment: Yes, the header should repeat in every row, and the items should take only a single index, but still be formatted like the original object (i.e., `header: data, items: [data_for_one_index]`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by *Are you allowed to assume the structure (i.e. header and items)?*, but I think yes. The general structure is known and unchanging.

Comment: By that I mean that if tomorrow a `"additional_property": 5` popped up in the structure, the query would need to be modified to take it into account, even if you're not "doing" anything with it. It is possible to write a more complicated query that could tolerate such changes transparently, but, well, more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement to repeat the other properties complicates this a bit, because we need to build a new object explicitly. Even so it's not *too* hard:

```sql
update someTable
set 
    [json] = (
        select (
            select 
                "header" = json_query(@json, '$.header'), 
                "items" = json_query(N'[' + items.item + N']')
            for json path, without_array_wrapper
        )
    ), 
    item_id = items.item_id
from openjson(@json, '$.items') with (
    item nvarchar(max) '$' as json,
    item_id varchar(50) '$.id.name',
    i int '$.id.i'
) items
join someTable on [someTable].i = items.i
```

Here I'm assuming the `@json` has already been unwrapped from its array, as your query seems to assume. If it's not, substitute `$.[0]` for `$` in the outer query.

Comment: @Matthew: Is `header` actually a string, as in your example, or an arbitrary object? `json_value` won't work in the latter case, and `json_query` should be used instead (which, in turn, will not work if `header` is actually a value).

Comment: Header is an arbitrary object

Comment: On test data the select seems to be working perfectly (although I'm getting a multi-part identifier could not be bound error on items.item), but the update is failing...

Comment: That's probably left for another question though... thanks for the help!!

Comment: I see the same issue in SSMS (18.1), but this appears to be a spurious error from Intellisense -- the actual T-SQL is sound (tested against an actual table).

Comment: Yes... any ideas on what might be causing a failed update? I have two chained together and the first one seems to work fine...

Comment: Without the source table that's hard to tell. I tested against `declare @t table (i int, [json] nvarchar(max), item_id varchar(50)); insert @t values  (0, '{"x":1}', 'item_id4'), (4, '{"x":2}', 'item_id7'), (17, '{"x":3}', 'item_id6');` (with deliberately mismatching data to verify the update works).

Comment: Ah, I was passing in an incorrect variable. Thank you for your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

It's an attempt to improve my answer (I missed the `header` part of the `JSON` content in the original answer). Of course, the @JeroenMostert's answer is an excellent solution, so this is just another possible approach. Note, that if `header` part of `JSON` content is scalar value, you should use `JSON_VALUE()`.

Table and JSON:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   i int,
   [json] nvarchar(max),
   item_id nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (i, [json], [item_id])
VALUES
   (0 , N'entire_object_at_index_0',  N'item_id'),
   (4 , N'entire_object_at_index_4',  N'item_id4'),
   (17, N'entire_object_at_index_17', N'item_id17')

-- JSON
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{
  "header": {"key": "some_data"},
  "items": [{
    "id": {
      "i": 0,
      "name": "item_id"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 4,
      "name": "item_id4"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 17,
      "name": "item_id17"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
  }}]
}]'
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET #Data.Json = j.Json
FROM #Data
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT
      JSON_QUERY(@json, '$[0].header') AS header,
      JSON_QUERY(j.[value], '$') AS items
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].items') j
   WHERE JSON_VALUE(j.[value], '$.id.i') = #Data.[i]
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
) j ([Json])
```

**Original answer:**

One possible approach is to use `OPENJSON` and appropriate join:

Table and JSON:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   i int,
   [json] nvarchar(max),
   item_id nvarchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (i, [json], [item_id])
VALUES
   (0 , N'entire_object_at_index_0',  N'item_id'),
   (4 , N'entire_object_at_index_4',  N'item_id4'),
   (17, N'entire_object_at_index_17', N'item_id17')

-- JSON
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[{
  "header": "some_data",
  "items": [{
    "id": {
      "i": 0,
      "name": "item_id"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 4,
      "name": "item_id4"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
    }
  }, {
    "id": {
      "i": 17,
      "name": "item_id17"
    },
    "meta": {
      "data": "some_data",
      "text": "some_text"
  }}]
}]'
```

Statement:

```
UPDATE #Data
SET [json] = j.[value]
FROM #Data
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      [value],
      JSON_VALUE([value], '$.id.i') AS [i]
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].items')
) j ON (#Data.[i] = j.[i])
```